# Is offsetting portions of grids possible when using a grid system?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, offset

I'm wondering if it is possible to offset by portions or percentages of grids instead of the whole grid width.

Let's say for example, I had:

```
   <div class="span1 offset6" >
```

...and I wanted it to the left a little more, should I just add an < id > and put a css "left" or is it possible to offset by something like 6.5 (for example)?

Maybe I'm over thinking it a bit (or maybe not enough :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just add a custom class to the top of your page with the amount you want to increase the offset. If you put the following style in your head:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .offset6-5 {
  margin-left: 540px;
 }
</style>
```

You now have a class that offsets in between Twitter bootstraps .offset6 class which has a 500px offset and the .offset7 class which has a 580px offset. You would of course have to be careful of throwing off the the rest of the grid system by creating custom widths that eventually change the overall grid size. (for example your 960px grid is now at 1000px.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it looked down upon to add a custom class to, lets just say, the content inside, maybe a header for example, and then add a "margin-left" in css so it spans first inside the offset column and then in the exact place you would like it?

Comment: I'm not a CSS expert myself but I would say it's generally better practice to include that in with the rest of your CSS instead of custom classes in the header. When I work with Twitter Bootstrap I usually either create a seperate file to include or clearly mark any changes I make to Bootstrap's CSS file just because I don't like to start tinkering with what is already proven stable and well documented.